# Sets $S=\{s_1,... ,s_n\}\subset \mathbb R$ s.t. $\forall \alpha\neq\beta\in \mathbb N^n,\prod_{i=i}^ns_i^{\alpha_i}\neq \prod_{i=i}^ns_i^{\beta_i}$

Tags: analytic-number-theory

I need some examples of "prime-like" sets of numbers. Maybe this term is already known by some other standard name. Let me define it. A set $S=\{s_1,s_2,\ldots ,s_n\}\subset \mathbb{R}$, is called "prime-like" if
$$\forall \alpha\neq\beta\in \mathbb{N}^n \mbox{ we have} \prod_{i=i}^ns_i^{\alpha_i}\neq \prod_{i=i}^ns_i^{\beta_i}$$

Obviously any set of $n$ distinct prime numbers are "prime-like". One other trivial example is inverse of $n$ distinct prime numbers. Can you provide some other interesting examples of such sets, preferably numbers having magnitudes $\leq 1$. If this definition is known by some standard name in mathematics, please provide the sources.

Moreover, are the following sets $S$  "prime-like"?
$$S=\{\cos(1),\cos(2),\ldots ,\cos(n)\}$$
or
$$S=\{\sin(1),\sin(2),\ldots ,\sin(n)\}$$

Comment: Isn't the "prime-like" condition equivalent to saying that the logarithms of the $s_i$'s are linearly independent over the rationals?

Comment: @AndreasBlass, Yeah. You are right. That seems to be the equivalent formulation.